# Could not understand how stdin and stdout in Popen fucntion works in Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm a a beginner in Python and love to execute shell commands through Python's subprocess module.
But have some doubts regarding the Popen constructor
Regarding: arguments stdin and stdout

Consider I'm doing a script to ping a website. Let it be "www.google.com" through shell command

Program #1:

```
import sys
import subprocess
cmdping = "ping -c4 www.google.com"    
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdping,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
while True:
    out= p.stdout.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

1. What exactly happens in stdout=subprocess.PIPE.If I'm right, stdout is for standard output.
   Then why we are using out = p.stdout.read(1)

And if my program is like

```
import sys
import subprocess
cmdping = "ping -c4 10.10.22.20"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmdping, shell=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
```

OUTPUT IS LIKE:

```
PING 10.10.22.20 (10.10.22.20) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 10.10.22.20: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.951 ms

UMR-AUTO root@1-2 #64 bytes from 10.10.22.20: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.612 ms

64 bytes from 10.10.22.20: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.687 ms

64 bytes from 10.10.22.20: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.638 ms



--- 10.10.22.20 ping statistics ---

4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.612/0.722/0.951/0.134 ms
```

Can you explain me this please??

I could not understand the how the process is happening and want to know accurately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) is a way processes can be chained together, so that they can communicate using standard streams. Here is a diagram that explains the various pipes and how you use them from wikipedia:

[image: Pipe Diagram from Wikipedia]

This means, that you can take the output of one process, and use it as the input of another process, and chain these processes together.

There are three main areas where you can plug in the pipes.  The standard output (stdout), then standard input (stdin) and the standard error (stderr) streams.

This allows you to redirect output to other applications.  For example, you might wish to redirect all error output to a program that sends this output to a database.

Now, when you want to execute a process from within your own program, you have to decide how you want to communicate with it.  However, there a lot of convenience methods available for most cases.  These use pipes underneath, but they provide a friendlier interface.

1. The simplest case is when you just want to run a process, and all you care about is if it was run successfully or not. For this, you use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

   ```
   if subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', 'www.google.com']) != 0:
      print('There was an error')
   ```

   There is also `subprocess.check_call`. They both do the same thing, the only difference is `check_call` will raise a `CallProcessError` exception if there was a problem. You can catch this and output the error message.
2. You want to run a command and grab the output, for this use [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

   ```
   try:

     result = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '1', 'www.google.com'])
     print('The result is: {}'.format(result))

   except subprocess.CallProcessError, e:
     print('There was an error: {}'.format(e))
   ```

   Here is what it will return:

   ```
   >>> result = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', '1', 'www.google.com'])
   >>> print(result)
   PING www.google.com (78.159.164.59) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 78.159.164.59: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=33.4 ms

   --- www.google.com ping statistics ---
   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 33.414/33.414/33.414/0.000 ms
   ```
3. Run a process, then send it some other commands. For this you use [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) and pipes.

   To be able to communicate with the process, you need to create a pipe and then get a handle to this pipe in your program.

   If you only want to send it commands, you would create a pipe to `stdin`, if you want to send commands, and then read the results - you need to create a pip to both `stdin`, and `stdout` (and optionally, stderr).

   In this example, from the python shell we are launching another python shell, then executing `import this` and reading the results:

   ```
   >>> handle = subprocess.Popen(['python'],
                                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
   >>> result, error = handle.communicate('import this')
   >>> print(result)
   The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

   Beautiful is better than ugly.
   Explicit is better than implicit.
   Simple is better than complex.
   Complex is better than complicated.
   Flat is better than nested.
   Sparse is better than dense.
   Readability counts.
   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
   Although practicality beats purity.
   Errors should never pass silently.
   Unless explicitly silenced.
   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
   Now is better than never.
   Although never is often better than *right* now.
   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
   ```

Finally, you'll notice that I am passing a list as my command. This is the recommended way to list the commands (and their options) that you want to launch.

You can use the `shlex` module to help you break up a command string into its various components:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> cmd = 'ping -c1 google.com'
>>> parsed_cmd = shlex.split(cmd)
>>> parsed_cmd
['ping', '-c1', 'google.com']
```

This is a simple example, but the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) shows a more complex example.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the response. But what does this "handle.communicate('import this')" mean. Usually Popen.communicate is used to communicate with the process and to get the output of the process. But this "import this" is looking strange and we are also getting an output for this

Comment: `import this` is the command I am sending to the process. `.communicate()` is a two way channel. Without any argument `handle.communicate()` you get the results.

Comment: I tried this                                                            from sys import *
import subprocess

handle = subprocess.Popen(['python'],
                              stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result, error = handle.communicate()
print(result)                                                              But it's showing empty output

Comment: Yes because you didn't send it anything to execute.